# Probability of a Random Variable Falling Between Two Ranges?

Tags: probability

Consider the following situation:

Take some integer $N$

Each day there is a:

- $p_1$ probability that $N$ will increase by $n_1$ % of its current value
- $p_2$ probability that $N$ will decrease by $n_2$ % of its current value
- $p_3 = 1- p_1+ p_2$ probability that $N$ keep its current value

For some fixed values of $N$, $n_1$, $n_2$, $p_1$ and $p_2$ -  the following expression can be written to represent the expected value of N at the 365th day:

$$E(N_{365}) = N \times [ p_3 + p_1(1+n_1) + p_2(1-n_2)]^{365}$$

**My Question:**  Assume some fixed values of $N, p_1, p_2, n_1, n_2$. On any given day (e.g. the $t^{th}$ day, $N_t$), I am interested in trying to find out the probability of $N$ taking certain values (e.g. $N_t$ falling between two ranges). For example, **what is the probability of $N_t$ being greater than some two constants $c_1$ and less than $c_2$?**

Here is what I have tried so far:

**Part 1:** Expected Value of N on the first day:

$$E(N_1) = N \times [ p_3 + p_1(1+n_1) + p_2(1-n_2)]^{1}$$

And by extension:

$$[ p_3 + p_1(1+n_1) + p_2(1-n_2)] = a$$
$$[E(N_1)]^2 = N^2*a^2$$

**Part 2:** Expected Value of $N^2$ on the first day:

By using the following relationship for Expected Values of Discrete Random Variables: $E(x^2) = \sum_x x^2 p(x)$:

$$[E(N_1^2)] = N^2 \times [ p_3 + p_1*(1+n_1)^2 + p_2*(1-n_2)^2]^{1} = N^2 * b $$

**Part 3:** Now, we can write the Variance of N on the first day as:

$$Var(N_1) = [E(N_1^2)] - [E(N_1)]^2  =  N^2 * b - N^2*a^2$$

**Part 4:**  For argument sake, let's quickly find out the Variance of $N$ on the second day:

$$E(N_2) = N \times [ p_3 + p_1(1+n_1) + p_2(1-n_2)]^{2} = N_1 * a$$

$$[E(N_2)]^2 = (N*a^2)^2 = N^2 * a^4 = (N_1)^2 * a^2 $$

$$[E(N_2^2)] = (N_1)^2*b $$

$$Var(N_2) = (N_1)^2*b  -  [(N_1)^2 * a^2] $$

**Part 5:** Thus, for any given day, we can now generalize the above formula as:

$$Var(N_t) = (N_{t-1})^2 * b - [(N_{t-1})^2 * a^2]$$

**This is where I got stuck.** Suppose if $N_t$ followed a Normal Distribution based on the following properties:

$$N_t \sim \mathcal{N} \left(N \times [ p_3 + p_1(1+n_1) + p_2(1-n_2)]^{t}, (N_{t-1})^2 b - [(N_{t-1})^2 a^2]\right)$$

I could then easily answer questions such as "what is the probability of $N_t$ being greater than $c_1$ and less than $c_2$"?  by integrating this Normal Distribution between ($c_1$, $c_2$). However, I am not sure if $N_t$ has a Normal Distribution.

**Can someone please show me how to proceed?**

Thanks!

**Note**:

- I understand that $N_t$ is a Discrete Random Variable. I know that in the case of Binomial Distribution and the Poisson Distributions (both of them are also Discrete Probability Distributions) - in certain situations, these can be well-approximated by a Normal Distribution (i.e. a Continuous Random Variable). This being said, I wonder if the Discrete Random Variable $N_t$ can somehow also be approximated by some Continuous Random Variable?

Comment: if $p_2>p_1$, then $p_3>1$. Enough.

Comment: Notice $\log(X_{t})$ is the sum of independent random variables so it's actually a random walk. There's a lot of theory on the behavior of random walks (that sadly I'm not too familiar with) that you may find useful. For example the CLT gives you a little bit of information on the distribution of $\log(X_{t})$ for large $t$.

Comment: @ FZan: thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following FZan's suggestion, let $L_t = \log (N_t/N)$.  Your question becomes "What is the probability that $\log(c_1/N) < L_t < \log (c_2/N)$?"  The Central Limit Theorem provides a good approximation to the answer. $L_t$ is a sum of $t$ independent random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $V$, where $$
\mu = p_1 \log(1+n_1) + p_2 \log(1-n_2),\;\text{and}\\
V = p_1 \log(1+n_1)^2 + p_2 \log(1-n_2)^2 - \mu^2.$$
The mean of a sum of random variables is the sum of their means.  The variance of the sum of *independent* random variables is the sum of their variances.  Therefore, $L_t$ has mean $t\mu$ and variance $tV$.  For simplicity, let's define a version of $L_t$ that has mean $0$ and variance $1$:$$
l_t = \frac{L_t - t \mu}{\sqrt{tV}}.$$

The Central Limit Theorem states that $l_t$ is approximated by a Gaussian increasingly well as $t$ increases.  The probability that a Gaussian random variable (with mean $0$ and variance $1$) falls between $a$ and $b$ (with $a \le b$) is$$
p(a,b) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right).$$
Putting it all together, the probability that $N_t$ falls between $c_1$ and $c_2$ (with $c_1 \le c_2$) is approximately$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\log(c_2/N)-t\mu}{\sqrt{2tV}}\right)-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\log(c_1/N)-t\mu}{\sqrt{2tV}}\right)\right).
$$